# Rails Activerecord dateTtime instead of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Mysql table:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| id | date       | time     |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | 2016-06-21 | 16:00:00 |
|  2 | 2016-06-23 | 16:00:00 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

db/schema.rb:

```
create_table "objs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date     "date"
  t.time     "time"
end
```

Dump object:

```
#<Obj:0x00000810ec38b8
 id: 2,
 date: Wed, 22 Jun 2016,
 time: 2000-01-01 16:00:00 UTC>
```

The value is "2000-01-01T16:00:00.000Z" but "16:00:00" expected.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using this calls:

```
obj.to_time.strftime("%T")
```

But what is the reason such behavior, especially from perfomance point of view? Don't know...